# Lambda SES forwarding function AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-iam

I'm using this email  [AWS SES forwarding script](https://github.com/arithmetric/aws-lambda-ses-forwarder) on a registered domain in AWS, along with releavant MX and TXT records. Personal emails im testing this with are also authorised as im in sandbox mode. I've set a rule in SES, pushing emails to an s3 bucket. After i call the aformentioned lambda function to redirect emails to anther gmail account.

```
var defaultConfig = {
fromEmail: "info@domainInRoute53.co.uk",
subjectPrefix: "",
emailBucket: "s3.xxxxx.xxxxx",
emailKeyPrefix: "emails/",
forwardMapping: {
"info@domainInRoute53.co.uk": [
  "personal@gmail.com",
  "personal@hotmail.co.uk"
  ]
 }
};  ..etc..
```

It writes to the s3 bucket but i cant seem to get it to forward to the personal email addresses.

I've tried numerous edits on the inline and managed policies in the IAM roles for the lamdba function to select, as suggested in the link I'm following above on step 2. Any ideas why this is failing?

Comment: The script documentation says the email forwarding address must be in lower case. Have you checked that?

Comment: yes. this is just example email

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? I think I have the same issue myself.